Discover the matched ids in PySpark as many as possible
I have a Spark DataFrame, like



id1
id2
score




A1
B1
9


A2
B1
9


A2
B2
7


A3
B2
5



I want to find best matched id1/id2 in PySpark and output is



id1
id2




A1
B1


A2
B2



The challenge is that Row(A2, B1, 9) has the highest score = 9, but B1 has been matched to A1, so A2 will match to B2. Match as many id1 to id2 pairs as possible, without reusing an id2 that has already been paired, even if it means choosing a lower score for some id1. This is more like a greedy assignment problem.
Do you know any way to do this in PySpark code?
Any idea and PySpark code is appreciated.

I find a simplest way to do that, but not sure whether it works or not.
result = df.orderBy(col("score").desc(), col("id2").asc(), col("id1").asc()) \
.dropDuplicates(["id2", "score"]) \
.drop("score") \
.select('id1', 'id2') \
.dropDuplicates(["id2"]) \
.dropDuplicates(["id1"])


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I have saw a matching algorithm they based on distance metric. Euklid in n-dimensional room. You are only 2 dimensional, so You can calculate simply vectors
enter link description here
the principle behind is to have a pool, calculate every distances and then go thru and remove every find pair from the pool. So in this example you cannot match B1 again, because they is out.
The algorithm calculate a vector from the Pool array
I found this, only fragments, I think this is Python :
diffVec[count] = np.power(np.sum(np.power(currentDiff,c)/numBins),1/c)

Module numpy

thanks Winfried. As the dataframe I used is a large one, Is ther any impact when using python vector pool to do that?

No, I dont think so. We use it in 3D, have a loop of 200 frequencies for each calculation. And we have more then 100 candidates. It tooks only a second, rather less.

I beleive this should work:
bc=ab.sort('id2','score')
bc=ab.groupby(col("id2")).agg(max("score"),first("id1"))

You can drop score column afterwards.
